# Understanding of Cache Method in C

Tags: c, caching

I'm pretty new to caching, and I was wondering if someone could help me understand this method.  How does it fetch a tag if it actually returns a whole cacheblock pointer?  What is *bIndex doing here, and what does its abbreviation mean?

```
cacheBlock* getTag(int index, int tag, int *bIndex) {
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < assoc; i ++ ) {   
    if (cache[index].block[i].tag == tag) {
      cacheBlock *targetBlock = &cache[index].block[i];
      *bIndex = i;
      return targetBlock;
    }
  }
  *bIndex = -1;
  return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there is a 'global' array of caches, `static cacheControl cache[SOMESIZE];` or equivalent (we can't tell the type of `cache` from the code; it might be a pointer to allocated data instead of a fixed array).  The entry in the cache to be searched is identified by `index`.  Within that cache entry, there are tagged cache blocks.  This code does a linear search for the cache block that is identified by the tag value passed into the function as `tag`.  The code does a linear search through the list of cache blocks within the cache entry (controlled by a size `assoc` which is not defined in the code — mysterious).  On exit from the function, the integer pointed at by `bIndex` contains the index number of the block within the cache (or -1); the return value is a pointer to the cache block.

Comment: That was very helpful.  So what's the difference between bIndex and index?  Isn't the index number the number of the block within the cache?

Comment: The `index` is an entry into the `cache` array and is an input parameter to the function. The `bIndex` is the entry number within the `block` array within a `cache` entry and is an output of the function.  So, one's an input; the other's an output.  And they are indexes into two different arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Analysis Below:

```
cacheBlock* getTag(int index, int tag, int *bIndex) 
{
  int i;

  // walk all blocks in cache[index] block[] table
  for (i = 0; i < assoc; i ++ ) 
  {
    // if the block association at this index matches this tag,
    //  then the block we're looking for is in the cache.   
    if (cache[index].block[i].tag == tag) 
    {
      // setup return value (this is unneeded, btw. simply setting
      //  *bIndex and returning (cache[index].block+i) would work).
      cacheBlock *targetBlock = &cache[index].block[i];

      // set out-param to inform them which block[i].tag matched in the
      //  block being returned by address. either this is actually not
      //  needed, or this is a bug, since we already return the precise
      //  block[i] entry by address (see above). the caller may like
      //  knowing *which* block[] entry matched for whatever reason.
      *bIndex = i;

      // return the matching cache[index].block[i] address
      return targetBlock;
    }
  }

  // no match condition. set offset to (-1) and return NULL.
  *bIndex = -1;
  return NULL;
}
```

That being said, I believe you should check the caller of this code, as the block[] entry they are receiving is already offset to the exact match they were looking for. i.e. the returned pointer does not need the *bIndex offset. If they use it to index-offset from the return address, i.e. they have code that looks something like this:

```
int bIndex = 0;
cacheBlock *pEntry = getTag(cache, tag, &bIndex);
if (pEntry != NULL)
{
    // do something with pEntry[bIndex]
}
```

it is likely a bug, and perhaps they intended to return `cache[index].block`, rather than `cache[index].block+i`.

Answer (score 0):

What the function is doing is to perform a linear search through an array of cache blocks.  It returns a pointer to one if it finds a match based on the given integer tag value. Perhaps comments in line might help:

```
cacheBlock* getTag(int index, int tag, int *bIndex) {
 int i;

 // The following iterates/increments through all? blocks for
 // the given cache index.  The variable assoc is global to this
 // function and I assume represents the number of entries for
 // each cache index.
 for (i = 0; i < assoc; i ++ ) {   
   // Check to see if a given block matches the one identified
   // by the passed in variable tag.
   if (cache[index].block[i].tag == tag) {
     // It did match so we will grab the address of that block
     cacheBlock *targetBlock = &cache[index].block[i];
     // And return (via parameter) the position at which it was found
     *bIndex = i;
     // And now return the address of (pointer to) the block
     return targetBlock;
   }
 }
 // we did not find the given entry, so pass back -1 as the
 // index to signify that.  And return NULL also to
 // signify that it was not found.
 *bIndex = -1;
 return NULL;
}
```